# How can I learn Shell Programming?

Tags: 11.04, 10.10, command-line, scripts

What are the tools needed for shell development, and are there examples?

Comment: Which languages do you already know?

Comment: Just run `man bash` and read.

Comment: Cristopher..Vb,Vb.Net,C++,Delphi,C#, Java(Middle)....

Answer (score 3):

The tools, the `bash` shell and the `sh` POSIX shell (provided by `dash`) are already available in Ubuntu by default.

You can begin by reading [Bash Reference Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html) and Lhunath's [BashGuide](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide).

Next, you should try yourself, follow this site and also [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com), where many shell related questions arise frequently.

Finally, a great source of interactive information is the #bash channel on Freenode IRC network.

Answer (score 1):

If you are into reading books, paperback or e-book, you should head for O'reilly  books:
[Learning the bash Shell](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596009656.do)
should be your first step.

Then when you are more proficient, get yourself: [Classic Shell Scripting](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596005955.do?green=DF96A6EE-757F-54E6-B5AE-7AAEC5404B1C&cmp=af-mybuy-9780596005955.IP)

Good luck, and happy study.

Answer (score 0):

[LinuxCommand](http://linuxcommand.org/) is a great starting point. It covers "the basics" of both bash and scripting and from there you can go to a more advanced guide.

I would also suggest you learn regular expressions, sed, awk, grep , all classics